# Use the current instance - Java

Tags: java, object

I am a newbie in Java and wanted to know how to call the current instance of the object instead of creating an object.
e.g-

```
class Token {

    public double generateToken() {
        return Math.random();
    }
}

class CallToken {

    public double callGeneretedToken(){
        Token token= new Token();
        return token.generateToken();
    }
}

public class TestToken {

    public static void main((String[] args) { 
        Token token = new Token();
        System.out.println(token .generateToken());
        CallToken callToken=new CallToken();
        System.out.println(callToken.callGeneretedToken());
    }
}
```

> O/P-
>
> 0.4404705200846246
>
> 0.05306690188022356

The thing is I want "CallToken" value should be same as  "Token"

Comment: Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the purpose of this program ? Cause you call twice method generateToken() so it's normal that it returns different values because it't calls Math.random() function

Comment: You are confusing the objects (token, calltoken) with the values they are returning. Do you want the objects to be the same, or the values of `math.random` returned by the objects to be the same?

Comment: David gave you the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528115/5914654). But I strongly recommend you to go through some course and tutorials to understand more the differences between a class, an object, an instance and a reference.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` produces a different (random) value each time you call it. If you want to have the same result each time the `generateToken()` is called (on a single instance of Token), you need to store the random value you get (say upon a first call of `generateToken()` in a field in the Token class.

For the same reason, you also need to invoke `generateToken()` on the same instance of `Token`. To do that, you need to store a reference to your `Token` instance to it with the `CallToken` class, rather than creating it each time.

for example:

```
class Token {

    private Double value = null; 

    public double generateToken() {
        if (value == null) {
           // value is null first time we call this. We generate our random value and store it in the field.
           value = Math.random();
        }
        // Every time we call this, we return the same value
        return value;
    }
}

class CallToken {

    private Token token;

    // CallToken needs to know what token to call- we need to supply it with a reference.
    public CallToken(Token token) {             
         this.token = token;
    } 

    public double callGeneretedToken(){            
        return token.generateToken();
    }
}

public class TestToken {

    public static void main((String[] args) { 
        // We first create the Token, then call it, then pass the reference to it to CallToken, so it can call it too, in callGeneretedToken() 
        Token token = new Token();
        System.out.println(token.generateToken());
        CallToken callToken=new CallToken(token);
        System.out.println(callToken.callGeneretedToken());
    }
}
```

EDIT: + some clarifications

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting the same value because are different objects, you're instancing an object manually in your main test method, and the `callGeneretedToken()` method in `CallToken` class is instancing another object.

You should have Token as an field in class CallToken and have getter to it.

> Ps. You need to change the `Token` class too, to only generate token when it's not existent otherwise when you call `generateToken` manually, the `Math.random()` will generate a new one.

See an example:

```
class Token {

    private double myGeneratedToken;

    public double generateToken() {
        if(myGeneratedToken == null){
            myGeneratedToken = Math.random();
        }
        return myGeneratedToken;
    }
}

class CallToken {
    private Token myToken;
    public double callGeneretedToken(){
        return myToken.generateToken();
    }

    public Token getToken(){
        return myToken;
    }
    public void setToken(Token pToken){
        myToken = pToken;
    }    
}

public class TestToken {

    public static void main((String[] args) { 
        CallToken callToken = new CallToken();
        Token token = new Token();

        callToken.setToken(token);
        System.out.println(token.generateToken());
        System.out.println(callToken.callGeneretedToken());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on **Singleton** design pattern.

By using this one You're basically reusing object's instance that was created once.

[Singleton pattern explanation on Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton)